# String format with positioned placeholders or equivalent

Tags: javascript, python, string

I would like to format a string using positional placeholders in **Javascript**. For example, in Python I could do:

```
st1 = 'name'
st2 = 'javascript'
sentence = "My %s is %s." %(st1, st2)
print(sentence)
```

And I would get

```
My name is javascript.
```

as the output. Clearly it wouldn't work out in javascript (at least not exactly the same way), I know of using `replace`

```
var st1 = 'name';
var st2 = 'javascript';
var sentence = "My %s is %s".replace('%s', st1);
console.log(sentence);
```

But that would only replace the first occurrence of '%s'.

Comment: Why don't you do like that: `"My %s is %s".replace('%s', st1).replace('%s', st2);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: In ES6, you can use string interpolation. For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var st1 = 'name';
var st2 = 'javascript';
var sentence = `My ${st1} is ${st2}`;
console.log(sentence);
```

It will replace the two strings inside the sentence.

Comment: I don't think he's asking for that.